# OnAddedToForm designer event for UserControl?

Tags: winforms

Is there an event for a UserControl that only fires the first time it is added to a form? I basically want to show a memmo on how to use the control to the user once they add the control into the form, but never show it afterwards (until they add another instance of this control).

Comment: How a memo should look and be displayed? I think, you can create custom designer for a userControl (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/35ea88wb(v=vs.110).aspx) and add memo there.

Comment: A simple MessageBox will do.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do that could be:

Use the event `ParentChanged` from `Control` : [Control.ParentChanged Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.parentchanged(v=vs.110).aspx)

`UserControl` is an heritance of `Control`

In your `UserControl`, you could use a private field to define if the item has been already added to a parent.

This code could work for you:

```
public class CustomUserControl : UserControl
{
    private bool _firstTimeAdded = false;

    private void Init()
    {
        this.ParentChanged += CustomUserControl_ParentChanged;
    }

    private void CustomUserControl_ParentChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Parent is Form && !_firstTimeAdded)
        {
            _firstTimeAdded = true;
            // Show your memmo
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nope, that does not work - it fires every time you re-open the form's designer (this is designer mode i need it for).